# How to implement "Two factor authentication" in iOS application?

Tags: ios, macos, security, authentication

I am locking my Mac screen with my Mac app. As I enters password it needs to unlock. The password should be generated internally. So I preffered  to implement it by using "Two way factor authentication". By this my iPhone app generates a token frequently as I enters the token in Mac application it has to unlock.

I found few APIs like  [Gauthify](http://www.gauthify.com) and [Authy](https://www.authy.com/). But they are generating tokens on their own apps(ie.,to get token from authy we need to install authy app in our mobile).

My requirement is without installing those apps,my app need to generate the token and communicate with my Mac.

Please guide me if any one had done it. Good suggestions are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

All these apps, including Google or any other apis use two step authentication. Here they generate a token with some private key and pass that to end user via sms or mail or any other medium. This sms or mail is registered with user in application database.

There is no need to use such app if you have your same app in your MAC and your ios Device. 
You just need to identify how will you pass that key.

1. If MAC is generating token, and you know which device is trying to connect with MAC, you can send that token in background to that ios Device and match that.  If you are using socket connections, this is option for you
2. When user enters Token, you can make a request to server to check that token. For this you need to send token genereated on MAC to server and save it somewhere. These tokens generally expires after some time, so run cron job to delete such tokens.

The apps you described use 2nd way to authenticate.

Hope this much help you. All depends your requirements and your approach :)

Cheers